# Reason-react rendering list of items from json

Tags: reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm learning reason react and am having trouble rendering a list of items I'm fetching from a json api.

```
let url = region => {
  "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_state="
  ++ Js.String.replaceByRe([%re "/\\s/g"], "_", String.lowercase(region));
};

[@react.component]
let make = (~region) => {
  let (breweries, setBreweries) = React.useState(() => []);

  React.useEffect1(
    () => {
      Js.Promise.(
        Axios.get(url(region))
        |> then_(response => {
             resolve(setBreweries(response##data));
           })
      );
      None;
    },
    [|region|],
  );

  let renderBrewery = brw => <div> {ReasonReact.string(brw##name)} </div>;

  <div>
    {breweries |> List.map(renderBrewery) |> Array.of_list |> React.array}
  </div>;
};
```

I am getting back the data I expect in the `then_` block. However, when the items are rendered I get a JS error saying `TypeError: brw is undefined` meaning that somewhere there is a discrepancy between the object I receive and the object I'm trying to render.

Comment: How _do_ you know that you receive the data you expect in the `then_` callback?

Comment: @glennsl a `Js.log` statement in the `then_` block shows the data I expect

Comment: You're getting JSON data over the network, it doesn't matter whether you're using plain JavaScript or ReasonML, you'll need to validate (decode) the data before you try accessing it. Try https://github.com/ryb73/ppx_decco for an easy way in ReasonML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is (almost certainly) that you're using `List.map` on an array.

Lists and arrays are not the same. The array `[|1, 2, 3|]` will be represented as an ordinary array in JavaScript, but a list `[1, 2, 3]` will be represented as nested two-element arrays, `[1, [2, [3, 0]]]` , with each array (cons-cell) containing one element and a pointer to the next cell, or `0` as a terminator.

`List.map` will continue to iterate until it encounters `0` as the second element of a cell, which of course it never does. Instead it continues to iterate on garbage data until it crashes.

The solution should be as simple as replacing `List.map` with `Array.map` and removing `Array.of_list` since that's now unnecessary.

It's also worth noting that this might have been prevented with type annotations, and almost certainly with JSON decoders. Having to spend time tracking down hard to catch errors like this is the price you pay for the convenience of dynamic typing.